# Openshift 3 - updating pip with build environment variable

Tags: python, environment-variables, openshift

I read in one the comments of a Openshift 3 Stackoverflow question that you can set a build environment variable to have your python project automatically update pip to the latest version. The variable is to be placed in the .s2i/environment file inside your project repo.  The variable is:

```
 UPGRADE_PIP_TO_LATEST=true
```

In reading the [Docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/using_images/s2i_images/python.html) for python build variables I see no mention of that particular variable.  Are the docs out of date?  Are there more undocumented environment variables that can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the link for the version of Python being used on that page and you will end up at:

- https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container/tree/master/3.5

This is where all configuration options are described.